# Call .reg File from Access

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, odbc, registry

I want to call a .reg file from AutoExec Macro in Access so that once the Access application opens an ODBC registry is installed.

The following is the code I write to create a function. I call the function in the AutoExec Macro. But when I run this, the ODBC registry is not installed into the machine.

```
Public Function ImportReg()
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%WinDir%\Regedit.exe /s R:\database2007\Testing\Test_Tool_ODBC.reg"
End Function
```

I tested the .reg file. If I double click, it works well and an ODBC registry is installed. That's why I think the problem may be the code.

I will be grateful if any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: No error message?

Comment: No error message.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not working? There might be a 32- vs 64-bit issue, check WOW6432Node for the keys you're trying to alter, it might be a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue. Generally, though, you might want to go DNSless so you won't have to rely on the registry

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's not working. Because when I double click to install, the Access DB can open. If I use this code to install, the Access DB can not open.